# Adding multiple options to PHP query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a property listing site and I need help with the code that filters search results.  The code below includes all properties with the contract type "southern-oregon".  I would like it to ALSO include contract types = to "medford-office".  Can someone tell me how to add that to the code?

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
echo $div; $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts(array('post_type'=>'property','post_status'=>'publish','paged'=>$paged, 
                  'author'=>$agent, 'property-contract-type'=>'southern-oregon'));
if(have_posts()):while(have_posts()):the_post(); 
$property_images = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'imic_property_sights',false);
$total_images = count($property_images);
$property_term_type = '';
$property_area = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'imic_property_area',true); 
$property_baths = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'imic_property_baths',true);
$property_beds = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'imic_property_beds',true);
$property_parking = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'imic_property_parking',true); 
$property_address = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'imic_property_site_address',true);
$property_city = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'imic_property_site_city',true);
$property_price = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'imic_property_price',true); 
$contract = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), 'property-contract-type', 
                                 array('fields'=>'ids')); 
$property_id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'imic_property_site_id',true);
$property_area_location = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'city-type');
$sl = '';
$total_area_location = count($property_area_location);
$num = 1;
foreach($property_area_location as $sa) {
    $conc = ($num!=$total_area_location)?'->':'';
    $sl .= $sa->name.$conc; $num++;
}
// We get Longitude & Latitude By Property Address
$property_longitude_and_latitude=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'imic_lat_long',true);
if(!empty($property_longitude_and_latitude)){
    $property_longitude_and_latitude = explode(',',
    $property_longitude_and_latitude); 
}else{
    $property_longitude_and_latitude=getLongitudeLatitudeByAddress($property_address);
}
global $imic_options;
$currency_symbol = imic_get_currency_symbol($imic_options['currency-select']);
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(),'150-100-size');
if(!empty($src)):
    $image_container= '<span class ="property_image_map">'.$src[0].'</span>';
else:
    $image_container='';
endif;  
if(!empty($contract)) {
    $term = get_term( $contract[0], 'property-contract-type'); $property_term_type = $term->name;
} 
if($design_type=='listing') { 
?>
```

Comment: Have you considered hiring a programmer?

Comment: I have a programmer that built this for me but he is not available right now.  I am just trying to make a quick edit to the code to fix our live site.  I appreciate the help, I understand this is probably a very simple question.

Comment: Fire your programmer.

Comment: I assume in the 4th line of the code example is where I need to add the additional variable to 'property-contract-type'=>'southern-oregon'.

Comment: Ah, developing in production by copy/pasting code from the internet. What could possibly go wrong ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect this is the core of your filtering system (significantly reformatted for readability - ask your developer to fix this please):

```
query_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged' => $paged, 
        'author' => $agent,
        'property-contract-type' => 'southern-oregon'
    )
);
```

At a guess, try replacing `'southern-oregon'` with an array, thus:

```
['southern-oregon', 'medford-office', ]
```

I would guess this would do an `IN`, which is essentially an `OR`.

Comment: That did the trick, I reformatted the code and added the array and it is now working properly.